# River drain: r.watershed to vector is not working

Tags: grass-gis, hydrology, vectorization

I want to vertorize the result of r.watershed (accumulation). After using r.to.vect I got the message that I have to use r.thin before. So I did, but the message comes again and again.

[image]

What I am doing wrong?
Is there a better way to get a map of "potential" rivers of my area?

Thanks!

Comment: What kinds of values are in your accumulation grid? Usually they comprise a great range of either integer or floating point values.  Floats usually cannot be vectorized.  Vectorizing integers treats each *distinct* value as designating a distinct feature: that's probably not what you want and why GRASS is complaining.  What kind of output are you looking for?

Comment: The output in the image above is exactly what I want, I just need it in vector, not raster. That part about the kind of values is a good point! How can I check and/or change that?

Comment: Usually, MAP, you can convert your output into a binary (0-1) image by comparing the stream accumulation to a threshold.  The exact threshold to use is a matter of trial and error, but a good starting point often is the equivalent of a few hundred cells (it depends on how the accumulation is actually measured and on the cellsize).  This makes all the heavier-flow streams into a *single* feature for extraction.  Thinning it may enable the software to extract it as a polyline instead of a polygon.

Comment: Thats it! I exported the raster to GeoTiff (converting to integer) and imported it back. So now its working perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can only vectorize lines, not continuous fields. Hence use r.mapcalc with a threshold to extract line structures from that map, then subsequently r.thin. Then it will work as expected.

See also this Wiki page for more possibilities: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/R.stream.*

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the stream output from r.watershed, rather than the flow accumulation.  It's an optional output; you'll need to make sure when you run r.watershed that you have a line similar to "stream=output".  From the help:

> stream
>
> Output map: stream segments. Values correspond to the watershed basin values.

You may need to use r.thin before you can successfully convert to (polyline) vectors.

Comment: I dont need the streams, accumulation like the image above is exactly what I want. But I also tryed to vectorize the stream - same problem with r.thin.